# Extracting tags from a string using a single regex capture in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string containing a set of tags that I want to match using a regular expression. Each tag is separated by a comma, and tags can contain spaces, special characters, and even emojis.

**Input example**

```
#
tag1, tag with space, !@#%^,
```

**Expected output**

1. tag1
2. tag with space
3. !@#%^
4. 

I've managed to extract the tags using the following C# code, but it feels clunky because it relies heavily on splitting and trimming:

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"^#[\n](?<tags>[\S ]+)$");
// if match is a success
var tags = match.Groups["tags"].Value.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
```

My goal is to create a regular expression that allows me to iterate through captures and extract the tags directly, without the need for additional string manipulation.

Is there a way to write such a regex that can extract these tags neatly and efficiently in C#? Ideally, the regex should trim leading or trailing whitespace and handle the variable fields of data in a single record.

Comment: Why not just split the string? `input.Split(",")` returns a string[] I don't see that as cheating

Comment: Got it. Did you know about `Regex.Matches` which returns a `MatchCollection` for all matches found in your input?

Comment: In C# (.net) regex it is possible to access repeated capturing groups as well es using `\G` for continuous matching - however I don't think your current approach is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand relationship of input and output, and why call it *tag*

Comment: Is this a one record string you're parsing here? `\G` construct shouldn't be used if you've got capture collections. It's error prone and a dog in performance. Capture collections would be better. Beware a regex style like Sebastian's. With no checks it would blow past into a new record, if you have more than one. Fwiw, there is no  _clean and short_ with all you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works  `(?ms)^\#\s+(?:\s*((?:(?!,|^\#\s+).)*?)\s*(?:,|$))+`

It uses C#'s *Capture Collection* to find a variable amount of field data
in a single record.

You could extend the regex further to get *all* records at once.
Where each record contains its own variable amount of field data.

The regex has built-in trimming as well.

Expanded:

```
 (?ms)                   # Inline modifiers:  multi-line, dot-all
 ^ \# \s+                # Beginning of record
 (?:                     # Quantified group, 1 or more times, get all fields of record at once
      \s*                     # Trim leading wsp
      (                       # (1 start), # Capture collector for variable fields
           (?:                     # One char at a time, but not comma or begin of record
                (?!
                     , 
                  |  ^ \# \s+ 
                )
                .         
           )*?
      )                       # (1 end)
      \s* 
      (?: , | $ )             # End of this field, comma or EOL
 )+
```

C# code:

```
string sOL = @"
#
tag1, tag with space, !@#%^, ";

Regex RxOL = new Regex(@"(?ms)^\#\s+(?:\s*((?:(?!,|^\#\s+).)*?)\s*(?:,|$))+");
Match _mOL = RxOL.Match(sOL);
while (_mOL.Success)
{
    CaptureCollection ccOL1 = _mOL.Groups[1].Captures;
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < ccOL1.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("  '{0}'", ccOL1[i].Value );
    _mOL = _mOL.NextMatch();
}
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
  'tag1'
  'tag with space'
  '!@#%^'
  '??'
  ''
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Another capture collection case for @Abel. Seems it's needed again.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with cheating ;]

```
string input = @"#
tag1, tag with space, !@#%^, ";

string[] tags = Array.ConvertAll(input.Split('\n').Last().Split(','), s => s.Trim());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pretty much make it without regex. Just split it like this:

```
var result = input.Split(new []{'\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Skip(1).SelectMany(x=> x.Split(new []{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(y=> y.Trim()));
```

Comment: That's exactly what he asked _not_ for.

Comment: That's describes why he should not use Regex for this task. He can, of course, but then he does not understand what Regex is made for. It is pattern matcher. Not a lexer, not a parser, just pattern-search DSL.

Comment: Read the question. He already did what you described in your answer on himself. So your answer is not an answer at all

Comment: And what is problem in splitting and trimming? Memory? Well, then he running for bits of complext optimization which actualy will not give him anything. First level memory, especially which involves strings is VERY fast.

Comment: Read the question, there are additional lines that should be avoided.